# Querying for key in array

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

My document structure looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("123781236712"),
  "statistic": {
    "1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        (...)
    },
    "5": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        (...)
    }

  }

}
```

I'm now trying to compose a find that gives me all documents that contains a `statistic.5`, no matter whats the content of "5".

So far, I tried without success:

```
db.statistics.find({"statistic": {$elemMatch: {$in:["5"]}}})
db.statistics.find({"statistic": {$elemMatch: "5"}})
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this tour PHP interpretation of what an array looks like? Or is this actually what your data looks like from the mongodb shell? If the latter then these are not actually arrays.

Comment: @NeilLunn thats the actual representation in the mongodb shell. The values are inserted as associative arrays from php like:
array("statistic" => array("5" => array(...)))

Comment: well i guess I solved it thanks to your broad hint that they are not actual arrays ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm now trying to compose a find that gives me all documents that
>   contains a statistic.5, no matter whats the content of "5".

For this exact question (with your current document structure), the query you posted will work perfectly:

```
db.statistics.find({"statistic.5":{$exists:true}});
```

Your query basically looks if the key exists in the document and this is exactly what you asked in your question.

However, your current document structure isn't very practical for some queries (that's what Neil is suggesting in his answer) and there is an alternative way to organize your document structure that's more flexible and easier to query using MongoDB.

I'm going to suggest a slightly different structure than Neil's:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("..."),
    "statistic": [
        { "key1": "value1", "key2" : "value2" },
        { "key1": "value3", "key2" : "value4" },
        { "key1": "value5", "key2" : "value6" }
        /* etc ... */
    ]
}
```

Creating an array of subdocuments (instead of creating an object with hashed key-value pairs) will enable you to do the following queries on your document.

This will be the equivalent to your query (and what you're looking for):

```
db.coll.find({"statistic.5" : { $exists : 1}});
```

You can also check the size of the array (if the array contains exactly X items):

```
db.coll.find({"statistic" : { $size : 5}});
```

And you can also search if **any** of the subdocuments contains a key with a specific value (which is something that your current structure doesn't support):

```
db.coll.find({"statistic.key1" : "value3");
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. The thing is that im getting this data as json from an api, is being slightly modified and then stored in MongoDB. As I have to be able to serve it in exact the same format again, refractoring just for storing it isnt really an option.
Queries like the above wont be done frequently anyways (only for statistical purposes).

Comment: @danijoo No problem :) In that case then it doesn't really make sense to change the schema.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is:

```
db.statistics.find({"statistic.5":{$exists:true}});
```

Comment: No it is not. This is **not** an array. The syntax works but you need to do that explicitly for every item. This is not the solution you want.

Comment: Read what has been said. Of course it works but it is not what you want.

Comment: What do I want then? Im not very experienced to mongodb but this seems to give me a correct solution. Whats a better approach?

Comment: this is the correct answer, but not for this question. the problem is actually with the question. either fix the question or delete it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

So pretty much as you were just told, you cannot use array operators on things that are not an array. Also "associative arrays" or "hashes" or "sub-documents" in MongoDB parlance are bad news to try and query.

Consider that you want to query for something that has "key3" equal to "value9". In your current format you would have to do:

```js
db.collection.find({
   "$or": [
       { "statistic.1.key3": "value9" },
       { "statistic.5.key3": "value9" },
       ... // and so on for every possible key
   ]
})
```

If you have an array like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "whatever",
    "statistic": [
        { "index": 1, "key1": "value1" },
        { "index": 1, "key1": "value2" },
        { "index": 5, "key1": "value1" },
        { "index": 5, "key3": "value9" }
    ]
}
```

Then all you need to do to query is:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "statistic.key3": "value9"
})
```

Simple.